# Merging 2 functions into one / sharing use state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react and typescript and I have two functions that do similar things except they use a different data set and also call two different functions. I have tried to merge them into one because the purpose of them is that if one sub-menu is open and I open another sub-menu then the first submenu will close. As they are separate when I open a sub-menu in one I can open a sub-menu in the other as well which I don't want.

I tried to merge by turning it into a single function and using an if statement and passing a string reflecting "dashboard" or "analysis" but I couldn't get it to work and it just completely broke my code.
I was wondering if anyone could help me merge my functions or at least share the state of if a sub-menu is opened/closed so only one sub-menu can only be open at any given time across both sections.

```
const DashboardsOpen = () => {
    const items = DashboardHeaders;
    const [openId, setOpenId] = useState<number | null>(null);
  
    const toggleHandler = (id: number) => () => {
      setOpenId(openId => openId === id ? null : id);
    };
    
    return ( 
    <div className="Sub-Menu-Items-Container">
         {items.map((item) => ( 
         <div key={item.id}> 
          <DashboardItems item={item} open={openId === item.id} onClick={toggleHandler(item.id)} />
         </div> 
         ))}
    </div> 
    )
}
```

The second function has two unique features which are Analysis Headers and calls the function AnalysisItems.

```
const AnalysisOpen = () => {
   
   const items = AnalysisHeaders;
   const [openId, setOpenId] = useState<number | null>(null);
 
   const toggleHandler = (id: number) => () => {
    
     setOpenId(openId => openId === id ? null : id);
   };
   
   return ( 
       
   <div className="Sub-Menu-Items-Container">
        {items.map((item) => ( 
        <div key={item.id}> 
         <AnalysisItems item={item} open={openId === item.id} onClick={toggleHandler(item.id)} />
        </div> 
        
        ))}
        
        
   </div> 
   )
 }
```

Main Wrapper which calls the functions

```
            <div className="Side-Pannel-Navigation-Main-Wrapper-Open">
                <Overview/>
                <div className="Side-Pannel-Section-Title">Dashboards</div>
                <DashboardsOpen/>             
                <div className="Side-Pannel-Section-Title">Analysis</div>
                <SearchBar placeholder="Search...." data={SearchData}/>
                <AnalysisOpen/>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to make two sub-menus where when one is open the other one is closed, and vice-versa. Right now, you are using two separate functions that both manage which `id` is open, but because they do it in their own functions they don't sync with each other which doesn't allow you to force one to stay open and the other closed.

I think instead of making each of them manage which `id` is open, you should make the Main Wrapper do it. You could simply send down the state to `<AnalysisOpen/>` and `<DashboardsOpen/>`. That is, something like this:

*Main Wrapper*

```
/* ... */

    const [openId, setOpenId] = useState<number | null>(null);
  
    const toggleHandler = (id: number) => () => {
     
      setOpenId(openId => openId === id ? null : id);
    };

    return (
        <div className="Side-Pannel-Navigation-Main-Wrapper-Open">
            <Overview/>
            <div className="Side-Pannel-Section-Title">Dashboards</div>
            <DashboardsOpen openId={openId} setOpenId={setOpenId}/>             
            <div className="Side-Pannel-Section-Title">Analysis</div>
            <SearchBar placeholder="Search...." data={SearchData}/>
            <AnalysisOpen openId={openId} setOpenId={setOpenId}/>
        </div>
    );

/* ... */
```

*AnalysisOpen* and *DashboardsOpen*

```
const xxxxxx = ({openId, setOpenId}: any) => {
   
   const items = AnalysisHeaders;
 
   const toggleHandler = (id: number) => () => {
     setOpenId(openId => openId === id ? null : id);
   };
   
   return ( 
       /* ... */
   )
 }
```

Doing it like this will ensure only one is displayed at a time.

Comment: This is the right answer. more info for the OP: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components